# Creating map using ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, software-recommendations

With what kind of tool/programm would you create such a map:

[image: map prototype, created with Apple Pages]

important criteria:

1. label and points need to be connected with a line
2. labels should have a bold headline
3. background color of labels should be changed individually (different layers only if not possible otherwise
4. the Map should automatically update edits in the excel file (.xls oder .xlsx) (attribte table are the Positions *"Pos. 1 ... n"* in ligns, attributes such as *Gitter*, *FW*,*Holzpfosten* etc und *lon*,*lat* in columns. In the cells is the amount of each attribute for the specific Position
5. last: particular own georeferenced maps should be added

Currently, I'm working with QGIS, where points 2,3,4 are not possible and bullet point 1 not as I wish (an extra layer is needed). Apart from that, it seems to be very userfriendly to me and is my major choice by now.
[map created with QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0o5F.png)

Personally, I'd prefer ArcGIS, because this is what I'm used to. But it is to complicated for the company I work for thus they only need it to label some points in the map. And they should be able to work with the map individually after I will have left the company (doing an internship here).
So I was thinking about alternatives such as ArcGIS online, ArcGIS for private user (but we use Macs here). I even tried google maps, but this doesn't work either.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to focus it on the most important requirement you are having trouble meeting and clarifying whether a QGIS solution is your preference, please?

Comment: I'm confused by your question which, in any event, seems to be asking for a software recommendation against a set of broad requirements that makes it a poor fit for our focussed Q&A format.  You say that QGIS cannot meet your requirements and yet you have a tag for that.  The ArcGIS Online tag I can understand.  What is "ArcGIS for private user"?

Comment: @PolyGeo: I'm sorry if I had made any mistake. I tried some programms to solve my issue but didn't find any optimal solution yet. Thus, I asked in this forum because I always got great answers in my last questions. If you say, this question did not fit into this Q&A, I would like to delete it. I tagged it with QGIS because I tried with QGIS and I didn't find an ideal other tag. ArcGis for private user is the "ArcGIS for Home Use Program"; it's for non commercial use (I work for an NPO company). thank you!

Comment: ArcGIS for Home Use is just a license of ArcGIS for Desktop, and that is what I would use to try and meet your requirements.  If you have any trouble meeting a particular requirement with that then you have a focussed question to research/ask here.